# Filter contact list by current month

Tags: filter

I have a list of employees with a birthday date/time field in the format of mm/dd/yyyy. I want to create a filter that will show me employees that are having a birthday in the current month.  How would I do this? I am using SharePoint 2007.

Thanks for your help.
Scott

Answer (score 1):

For this you have to use Calculated column.

1. Specify a column name (use like BirthdayThismonth)
2. For type select “Calculated based on other columns”
3. For the formula use

   ```
   =IF(MONTH([Today])=MONTH([birthday date]),"Yes","No")
   ```

So now your column will contain either value Yes or No based on Calculated field.

4. Now create a new view with filter where BirthdayThismonth is equal to Yes.

This will get you all items having birthday this month

Comment: Thank you for the response.  When I use the formula above I get "Calculated columns cannot contain volatile functions like Today and Me." and it will not let me save the column. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

So I came across this issue as well, and tried Amit's answer but like the OP commented on his post, it gives you the error: `Calculated columns cannot contain volatile functions like Today and Me.`

So the function is almost correct, but the following is what worked for me:

```
=IF(MONTH(NOW())=MONTH([Birthday Date]),"Yes","No")
```