# Birthday List View

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, list-view, modern-experience, date

Using Modern SharePoint.

I would like to create a SharePoint view that only displays the birthdays that fall within the current month.

My list has a name(TEXT) column and birthday(DATE) column.

I would like to stay away from using Power Apps or Power Automate. I feel like I keep running into logic roadblocks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow these steps:

1. Create a calculated column in list using below formula (say with name `BirthdayThismonth`):

   ```
   =IF(MONTH(NOW())=MONTH([Birthday Date]),"Yes","No")
   ```
2. Now filter a list view where `BirthdayThismonth` is equal to "Yes"

**Reference**: [Filter contact list by current month](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/132178/filter-contact-list-by-current-month)

---

**OR**:

1. Create a calculated column for the Start date of Month using formula like:

```
=DATE(YEAR([Birthday Date]), MONTH([Birthday Date]), 1)
```

2. Create another calculated column for the End date of Month using formula like:

```
=DATE(YEAR([Birthday Date]), MONTH([Birthday Date])+1,1)-1
```

3. Then filter list view using conditions like:

```
[Today] >= First Day Of Month

AND

[Today] <= Last Day Of Month
```

**Reference**: [Create SharePoint View Filtered by current Calendar Month,week and Year](http://sivanesanb.blogspot.com/2011/11/how-to-use-filters-in-sharepoint-to.html)

Comment: Thank You! That was exactly what I needed!

Comment: You're welcome, glad it worked for you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use any date column and reference it in a calculated column formula to extract/return the month value.

I have something set up for reception to record when a parcel was received (Time Received date column).  The column on the end is a calculated column, it's called *Month*.

[image: calculated column]

**Create a new column**

[image: create new calc column]

You substitute my column name for your own, so instead of [Time Received] you'd need [Birthday].

The "MMM" means that it will return a March date as Mar using three characters.
=TEXT([Time Received],"MMM")

Your formula would be:
=TEXT([Birthday],"MMM")

Be careful with the formula, the commas, speech marks and brackets need to be in the right place.  Sharepoint is fussy with this.